# Select student record based on foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, razor

I am working on MVC. I need to selecr list of students based on enrolled department wise and display them
on different divs departmentalize, based on enrolled department in view.
My database sample Schemas is as follow

Student Table

```
ID, Name
```

Enrollment Table

```
ID
Depart_id
Stdref_id
```

Department Table

```
ID
DepartName
```

I am trying something like this:

```
public ActionResult NewStudentFeeStatus()
    {
        IEnumerable<tblStdDetail> mdl = null;
        var departments= (from d in db.tblDepartments select d).ToList();
        var query = "";
        List<StdListModel> model = new List<StdListModel>();
        foreach (var item in departments)
        {
            query = (from p in db.tblStdDetails
                     join e in db.tblStdEnrollments on p.ID equals 
                     e.StdReg_ref_id
                     where e.Depart_ref_id == @item.ID
                     select p).ToList();

        }
        return View();
    }
```

I need a direction or sample code to follow for required output. I don't know what to do next and how to manage it in view. 
Kindly help me if you have any idea.

Comment: And what is your question? What problem are you having? (and your not even returning a model to your view)

Comment: I need a direction or sample code to follow for required output. I don't know what to do next and how to manage it in view.

Comment: @lilli, firstly, you cannot set the list for a single string variable `query`. Fix your code and tell us what you actually wanted to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this (I implemented your issue !!):

**DB Tables**

[image: Model]

**Action**

```
public ActionResult NewStudentFeeStatus()
        {
            ViewBag.DeparmentList = db.tblDepartments.ToList();
            List<tblStdEnrollment> enrollmentList = (from p in db.tblStdDetails
                                                     join e in db.tblStdEnrollments on p.ID equals e.Stdref_id
                                                     select e).ToList();
            return View(enrollmentList);
        }
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<tblStdEnrollment>    

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>NewStudentFeeStatus</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.DeparmentList)
        {            
            <div>@item.DepartName</div>
            foreach (var student in Model.Where(s => s.Depart_ref_id == item.ID).ToList())
            {                
                <div>@student.tblStdDetail.Name</div>
            }
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need to separate the students in view departmentalize in diff divs like the first div only contain IT students, 2nd div contain CS students etc.

Comment: @lilli You need to separate by `Depart_ref_id`?

Comment: I have accepted it as a correct answer thanks for help